# Why sed is not honouring the regex replace request

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, grep

I have a grep result like this

```
Nov-06-22 00:01:16 id-03674-09704 
Nov-06-22 00:01:16 id-03642-04246
```

and I need to remove from result the `id-.....-.....` part.

I am using this:

```bash
grep file.txt | sed 's/ id-(\d){5}-(\d){5}/ /g'
```

but it returns this

```
Nov-06-22 00:01:16 id-03674-09704 
Nov-06-22 00:01:16 id-03642-04246
```

I checked the regex `id-(\d){5}-(\d){5}` and it should be ok.

Why `sed` is not replacing the grep result?

Comment: See [Why doesn't `\d` work in regular expressions in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671293/why-doesnt-d-work-in-regular-expressions-in-sed) and [Capturing groups and interval quantifiers do not work in sed regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923147/capturing-groups-and-interval-quantifiers-do-not-work-in-sed-regex)

Comment: Your pattern is right, just need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]`

Comment: No, it is not just about lack of `\d` support. Here, OP's problem is also misunderstanding of regex flavors used by `sed`, let alone the quantifier and `grep` usage issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using POSIX BRE regex flavor with `sed`, `\d` are not recognized as digit matching construct, and `{5}` are treated as literal `{5}` strings, not interval quantifiers.

You need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` and use the `-E` option to enable POSIX ERE syntax (or escape the interval quantifier braces):

```bash
sed -E 's/ id-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}//' file
sed 's/ id-[0-9]\{5\}-[0-9]\{5\}//' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Dvpl7G):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='Nov-06-22 00:01:16 id-03674-09704 
Nov-06-22 00:01:16 id-03642-04246'
sed -E 's/ id-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}//' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Nov-06-22 00:01:16 
Nov-06-22 00:01:16
```

Also, consider just [removing last column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234436/279389) with `awk`, or even with `cut`:

```bash
awk 'NF{NF-=1};1' file.txt
cut -d' ' -f1,2 < file.txt
```

Comment: @gr68 You are not using  POSIX ERE options after `sed` here (like `-E` or `-r`) so you are using POSIX BRE.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it using `cut` by specifying the delimiter which I suppose is space in your case. You first need to read your file and do the grep then use `cut` command. Suppose you already have a file with the selected lines then you can use `cut` as below:

```
cat file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1,2
```

output:

```
Nov-06-22 00:01:16
Nov-06-22 00:01:16
```

Comment: `grep file.txt` would search its standard input for the pattern _file.txt_. The synopsis for _grep_ is: `grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]`.